# Firebase Query Error Handling

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got some functions to read data from Firebase, but sometimes I never get a response (or it's massively delayed).  I read [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-firebase-stuck-loading-forever/31146) that maybe Firebase can close the socket connection before data is received.  It looks like someone had a similar issue [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/firebase-talk/162spxynwj/firebase-sometimes-the-data-is-not-loading), but never posted a solution.

Here's a sample of my code for downloading user data from Firebase.

```
// loads the current user's information
static func loadUserDataWithCompletion(completion: (UserInfo) -> Void) {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    print("loading current user data...")

    let uid = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!
    ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().queryEqualToValue(uid).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        print("found user data!")
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            let info = userFromDict(dictionary)

            // execute code slated for completion
            completion(info)
        }
    })
}
```

Is there some way I can detect errors using `observeEventType`?  Maybe then I'd at least get more information about why the issue is happening.

Answer (score 6):

There can be three possible errors that you might face while observing your database :-

- You haven't defined a proper path to your database **`observe`** query
- You are parsing in a wrong or faulty manner
- You don't have the permission to access that particular node at that particular time(**Security Rules**)

For the first two you have to take care of it yourself, But for the third condition you can use ***withCancel*** block:-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: "uid").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        //your code
        }, withCancel: {(err) in

            print(err) //The cancelBlock will be called if you will no longer receive new events due to no longer having permission.

    })
```

- As far as error handling if the user looses network connection while *Writing*, ***Your app remains responsive regardless of network latency or connectivity.*** See the *Write data offline* section of [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into those possibilities and let you know if I find a fix.

Comment: It did not, I still haven't found a solution. :(  Once this project is more stable I'm going to try to isolate the issue and see if I can reproduce it.